# Can't change user roles dynamically with token and session

Tags: authentication, symfony, session, token, roles

**Update** : It works, just add isEqualTo() method in the User Entity (don't miss entity implements EquatableInterface)

It's ok! Add this to the Entity User :

public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user): bool
{
if ($this->id !== $user->getId()) {
return false; // Force la reconnexion
}

```
if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
    return false; // Force la reconnexion
}

// Important : Pas de vérification pour les rôles

return true;
```

}

==========================

Problem : In Symfony 6.2, I just can't add role dynamically just after the user authentification the role is still ROLE_USER. An idea ?

I tried this two solutions but User role doesn't change in the current session. The role ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_TEST can't be added dynamically to the sessions just after login..

```
   class UserLoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface

   {

    private TokenStorageInterface $storage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $storage)

    {

        $this->storage = $storage;

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()

    {

        return [

            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin',

        ];

    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)

    {

        // TRY 1 : doesn’t works

        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']);

        $event->getAuthenticationToken()->setUser($user);

 

 

        // TRY 2 : doesn’t works

 

        $user = $this->storage->getToken()->getUser();

        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN']);

        $o = new PostAuthenticationToken($user, 'main', ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']);

        $this->storage->setToken($o);

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot